# Still don't have enough skill points. What am I missing?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I am LVL 52 in horizon, i have all cauldrons, tallnecks, side quests, errands, tutorials, metal flowers, bunok figures, corrupted zones, bandit camps, and all blazing sun's in all hunting trails but I still need 15 skill points. Currently on the loaming shadow, where I must rest before the battle. Am I missing something? I should have them all before I finish the game, right?

Answer (score 8):

Since you are level 52, I can safely assume you have the Frozen Wilds Expansion.

Let's break down which skill points you can obtain. [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/8f6ak5/skill_point_sources/) has a very nice breakdown. With the Frozen Wilds Expansion, there are a total of 101 skill points available

- 17 skill points can be obtained by story quests
- 4 skill points can be obtained by side quests
- 20 skill points can be obtained by activities
- 60 skill points can be obtained by levels

**Unclaimed Skill Points**

- You are level 52, meaning you have a total of 8 more skill points you can acquire by levels. This leaves only 7 unaccounted for.
- Since you are on a [The Looming Shadow](https://www.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/The_Looming_Shadow), you are missing the skill point you get for finishing the [final quest](https://www.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/The_Face_of_Extinction). This leaves 6 unaccounted for.
- You didn't list out finding all Vantage Points. According to reddit, you get 1 skill point per set. It's been a while since I've played Horizon Zero Dawn, but if this is accurate, you can get 3 skill points from this. This leaves 3 unaccounted for.
- If you have covered all the basis from above and you are still short skill points, you can always grind the final mission until you have unlocked all the skills.